# Lizmap web client : Styling WMS layer according to Time manager date selected

Tags: wms, qgis-server, lizmap

I would like to style a layer according to a date selected with the time manager of Lizmap.

I succeeded to achieve this with the QGIS Temporal Controler. For my layer I put some styling rules based on a field date and compared to  *@map_end_time* -> this is working on QGIS.
But it's not working in Lizmap web client.

I tried also to add a dimension Time or Date in the property layer ([inspired by Paul Blottiere's article](https://pblottiere.github.io/2020/10/06/wmst/)) but Lizmap Time manager seems to not add the Key TIME or DATE in the request.

Any idea how I can achieve to styling the layer based on the Lizmap Time Manager ?

Configuration :

- Lizmap Web Client Informations

  - Version    3.7.0
  - Date   2023-12-13
  - URL
    dans l'extension QGIS bureautique QGIS Serveur Version Nombre
    3.28.13 Nom     Firenze ID du commit    3b4db4f5618 Py-QGIS-Server  not used Extensions Extension   Version Lizmap server   2.8.1
    wfsOutputExtension   not found

Comment: Hi, Time manager in QGIS and Lizmap are very different. Lizmap uses the `FILTER` parameter with WMS GetMap requests. Lizmap would need a refactoring to use WMS dimension. But I'm not even sure QGIS Server would make the link between WMS dimension request and time expressions as `@map_end_time` or `@animation_end_time` for example. You can test by yourself or ask QGIS community and give here your feedback.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, unfortunately even with `@map_end_time` or `@animation_end_time` I cannot manage to request and link with time expressions.